# Composing Attributes in Elixir

Tags: elixir

Since attributes are inlined once the module is compiled, I assume their values are constant. If possible, I'd like to define an attribute in terms of previously created attributes. I also want to be able to access them from the outside, my current approach is this

```
@required_fields ~w(email)
@optional_fields ~w(password role name last_name age country)

def required_fields, do: @required_fields
def optional_fields, do: @optional_fields

@all_fields required_fields ++ optional_fields
def all_fields, do: @all_fields
```

but I get this error

> == Compilation error on file web/models/user.ex ==
>   ** (CompileError) web/models/user.ex:22: undefined function required_fields/0
>       (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.@/1
>       web/models/user.ex:22: AristaServer.User (module)
>       (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:97: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8

Any way to achieve something similar? I don't want to recalculate the `all_fields` list everytime, seems wasteful. Also, I don't want to have to copy and past both list into a third list, looks error prone.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've run a benchmark, your intuitions about what is "wasteful" in elixir are probably wrong. I know that has been the case for every benchmark I've run. 
Just do this and worry about what is fast or slow after it's working.

```
 def all_fields, do: required_fields ++ option_fields
```

https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth

My thinking is that using Module attributes is likely more wasteful of memory since those get converted to multiple items in the code. If you leave it in a variable, it only gets created once in memory. But that is just a guess.

However if you really want to combine module attributes, you can do it like this.

```
@all_fields @required_fields ++ @optional_fields
def all_fields, do: @all_fields
```

Your problem arises because you can't use a function from the module to define a module attribute.

Comment: Does Elixir have memoization on special cases like this? If not, I can't imagine how it would speed up `all_fields` and avoid calling the `++` operator which is O(n).

Comment: The ++ operator is only 0(n) with mutable data. If the data items are immutable ++ is 0(1), (i.e. when you get to the end of this list, start on the next list. ). I've no idea if this is actually how ++ is implemented, but it's an example of how all your intuitions about what is fast get thrown out the window in an immutable data environment.

Comment: I dug into the code and `x ++ y` is O(size of x), so it's in between. It copies x and then just points the tail of x to the head of y.

Answer (score 1):

```
@required_fields    ~w(email)
@optional_fields    ~w(password role name last_name age country)
@all_fields         @required_fields ++ @optional_fields


def required_fields, do: @required_fields
def optional_fields, do: @optional_fields
def all_fields,      do: @all_fields
```

---

<sup>*I doubt you need both module attributes and public methods; consider using only one (If you use them within the module only, module attributes should do the job, otherwise you should go with public methods).*</sup>